# Trying to properly iterate through pygame sprite group

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, 2d-games

So I am building a simple infinite run game for school and I am stuck on trying to spawn the obstacles. I am trying to check each obstacle sprite and if it has gone off the screen (the background and obstacles move from right to left). If it has gone off screen, I want to remove the sprite and set up another one on the right side of the screen. But every time an obstacle goes off the left side of the screen, an infinite amount of obstacles start spawning. I am new to pygame and python in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
def obstacle_off_screen(self):
    numDeleted = 0
    for cur_sprite in self.all_objects_list:
        print("first loop")
        if cur_sprite.rect.x < 0:
            print("second")
            cur_sprite.kill
            numDeleted += 1
    while numDeleted != 0:
        print("third")
        self.add_obstacle()
        numDeleted -= 1

def add_obstacle(self):
    #add parameters
    if self.get_Speed() == 15:
        x = 1000
        y = 400
    elif self.get_Speed() == 20:
        x = 1000
        y = 400
    elif self.get_Speed() == 25:
        x = 1000
        y = 400
    elif self.get_Speed() == 30:
        x = 1000
        y = 400

    self.all_objects_list.add(Obstacle('src/paw.gif', [x, y]))
```

For now, I only have one obstacle that I initially spawn

Answer (score 2):

`cur_sprite.kill` is a function, so when you want to call it use `()`, like `cur_sprite.kill()`.

That's your problem. The obstacles out of screen don't get removed from their sprite groups.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. Works perfectly. Pretty stupid mistake.